# syntax error missing ), don't know where to place it in order to echo input

Tags: php, javascript

I want to know what is the correct way of display a text input in an echo in the code below because nothing is being outputted:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo $result; ?>,
    '<?php echo "<input name='vidid' type='text' value='".$id."'/>" . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>'
  );
</script>
```

The error I am recieving is: `syntaxError: missing ) after argument list.`

Comment: What does the final output of those PHP snippets look like?

Comment: Show the page source after it has been rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always escape your outputs:

```
window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>,
    <?php echo json_encode("<input name='vidid' type='text' value='".$id."'/>" . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']); ?>
);
```

In this case, you're outputting values that should be used in JavaScript, so use `json_encode()` to write valid JavaScript values.

Comment: Hi issue I got with your answer is that it does not output a text input, instead it outputs the text `<input name='vidid' type='text' value='26'/>` for example

Comment: @user1964964 That's what your code would do too if it worked :) it's passing an HTML string to a JavaScript function.

Comment: Is there a way I can display it as an actual text input?

Comment: @user1964964 That should be a separate question, because it's not clear what exactly `stopVideoUpload()` does.

Comment: OK, I will send you a link to the sperate question to you here

Answer (score 2):

Escape your quotes

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo $result; ?>,
    '<?php echo "<input name=\'vidid\' type=\'text\' value=\'".$id."\'/>" . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>'
  );
</script>
```

depending on what $result is - should be a number or it must be quoted too
We also need to know what $_FILES contains so please post the rendered view-source of what you have now

The escaping should make it look like

```
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    10,
    '<input name=\'vidid\' type=\'text\' value=\'someId'/> bla'
  );
```

This is easier to read

```
 '<?php echo '<input name="vidid" type="text" value="'.$id.'" />' . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>'
```

which gives

```
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    10,
    '<input name="vidid" type="text" value="someId"/> bla'
  );
```

Comment: But `$_FILES['fileVideo']['name']` might break the output again.

Comment: @mplungjan Problem is that because I am using an iframe to navigate to this page, I am unable to show what $_FILES show in the page source. I tried looking for it after uploading file but it does not show the output for this in the view source